# If more than one prime number satisfies a given congruence, must an infinite number of primes satisfy that congruence?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, congruences

I understand that this is kind of a broad question, but if no affirmative proof is known, can anyone give a counterexample?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're talking about *linear* congruences of the form $x \equiv a \bmod b$, then the answer is yes.

The key point is that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides every solution $x$. Thus:

- If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then there are an infinite number of prime solutions. This is the famous [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).
- If $\gcd(a,b)$ is composite, then there are no prime solutions.
- If $\gcd(a,b)=p$, then there is at most one prime solution, $x=p$. (In fact,  there is a prime solution iff $\frac ap \equiv 1 \bmod \frac bp$, but this is not relevant.)

Therefore, the only case when there is more than one prime solution is the first case, in which there are an infinite number of prime solutions.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I can't believe the answer is yes.

Comment: Another way of phrasing the argument: Let $p_1, p_2$ be two primes satisfying the congruence.  Then $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $p_1$ and it divides $p_2$; therefore it divides $\gcd(p_1, p_2)$.  But this is always 1, so $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and Dirichlet's theorem applies.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, yes indeed, thanks! I just thought I'd consider all cases.